# siunitx "table-number-alignment" does nothing

Tags: siunitx

I'm using Overleaf to compile my LaTeX code and I'm trying to use the `S` column type, but the `table-number-alignment` option does not seem to do anything. Here is an example directly from the `siunitx` documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Aligning the \texttt{S} column.}
    \label{tab:S:align}
    \centering
    \sisetup{
        table-figures-integer = 2,
    }
    \begin{tabular}{
        S
        S[table-number-alignment = center]
        S[table-number-alignment = left]
        S[table-number-alignment = right]
    }
    \toprule
    {Some Values} & {Some Values} & {Some Values} & {Some Values} \\
    \midrule
        2.3456 & 2.3456 & 2.3456 & 2.3456 \\
        34.2345 & 34.2345 & 34.2345 & 34.2345 \\
        56.7835 & 56.7835 & 56.7835 & 56.7835 \\
        90.473 & 90.473 & 90.473 & 90.473 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output I'm getting (note that in spite of the different `table-number-alignment` options the alignment is the same in all columns):

[image]

And here is what it shows in the `siunitx` documentation (note the alignment is different in each column):

[image]

**How do I get the `table-number-alignment` to work properly (like it shows in the documentation)?**

[EDIT]: I find that if I explicitly add a `table-format = 2.4` to each column I get the expected behavior. However, this is not required in the MWE code from the documentation, so what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `table-alignment-mode = format`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the manual, there are two options: `table-alignment-mode` and `table-number-alignment`. By default, `table-alignment-mode` is set to `marker`, which simply centres numbers such that all decimal markers are in the middle ignoring information from `table-number-alignment`.

On the other hand, when `table-alignment-mode` is set to `format`, `table-number-alignment` is taken into account (see [siunitx](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf), page 44 and 45).

The following MWE seems to do what you want:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\sisetup{
    table-format = 2.4,
    table-alignment-mode = format,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbh]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
        S
        S[table-number-alignment = center]
        S[table-number-alignment = left]
        S[table-number-alignment = right]
    }
    \toprule
    {Some Values} & {Some Values} & {Some Values} & {Some Values} \\
    \midrule
        2.3456 & 2.3456 & 2.3456 & 2.3456 \\
        34.2345 & 34.2345 & 34.2345 & 34.2345 \\
        56.7835 & 56.7835 & 56.7835 & 56.7835 \\
        90.473 & 90.473 & 90.473 & 90.473 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]